# What is the proper way to handle units in a csv file using python csv or pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

consider a csv file:

```
z,      a,    error,   b,   error
cm,    kg,    dl ,     kg,  dl
1.0 ,  2.0,    3.0,   4.0,  5.0 
1.1 ,  2.1,    3.1,   4.1,  5.1 
1.2 ,  2.2,    3.2,   4.2,  5.2
```

The first line tells us what the variable is. The second line here describes something about the data which is the units of each of the variables. One way would be to ignore the second line which is currently I am doing.

Is there a more consistent way of doing this than ignoring the second line?

Comment: You cannot ignore the second line: you have two `error` in first line. I would read the first two line and the the labels, and then read the file again, but telling pandas to use my labels (and my labels are something like `weight_kg`, `width_cm`, etc.) - Note: I use often such approach, e.g. to find separator, dtypes, etc.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how neatly you can access the columns and rows.

Answer (score 0):

There is! You can tell `pandas` that your `csv` contains more than one header row.

> **header : int, list of int, None, default ‘infer’**
>
> Row number(s) to use as the column names, and the start of the data. [. . . ] The header can be a list of integers that specify row locations for a multi-index on the columns e.g. [0,1,3] [. . . ] ([pandas documentation on `read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html))

Input `csv`

```py
z,a,error,b,error
cm,kg,dl,kg,dl
1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0
1.1,2.1,3.1,4.1,5.1
1.2,2.2,3.2,4.2,5.2
```

Open it

```py
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv, header=[0,1])
```

Your Dataframe

```
     z    a error    b error
    cm   kg    dl   kg  dl.1
0  1.0  2.0   3.0  4.0   5.0
1  1.1  2.1   3.1  4.1   5.1
2  1.2  2.2   3.2  4.2   5.2
```

You can now easily access the columns and rows.

Result of `df["z"]`

```py
    cm
0  1.0
1  1.1
2  1.2
```

Result of `df.loc[1, "z"]`

```py
cm    1.1
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Yeah, but it would be ugly to access data (now you have a multi-index)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi `df.columns = ['_'.join(x) for x in df.columns.to_flat_index()]` brings to what you described in the other comment.

Comment: You can easily access the column by name: `df["z"]` and you can easily access it by row index and name, too: `df.loc[1, "z"]`